# Best way to test before_action of parent controller with MiniTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have a subscribers section in my application with several controllers which inherited from Subscribers::BaseController

Subscribers::BaseController has a before_action :require_subscription

```
class Subscribers::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_subscription, if: :require_subscription?
  
  private

  def require_subscription
    RequireSubscriptionService.call(current_user)
  end

  def require_subscription?
   # several conditions
  end
end
```

And other controllers for example

```
class Subscribers::EventsController < Subscribers::BaseController
  skip_before_action :require_subscription, only: :other_action

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def other_action
  end
end
```

What is the best way to test, that `before_action :require_subscription` will be called if it necessary in each action with MiniTest

Usually I use Rspec, and I can use expect matcher in this case
For example

```
describe 'Subscribers::EventsController' do
  describe '.index' do
   expect_any_instance_of(described_class).to receive(:require_subscription).and_return(:return_value)
   subject
  end

  describe '.other_action' do
   expect_any_instance_of(described_class).not_to receive(:require_subscription)
   subject
  end
end
```

But how to test this stuff with MiniTest?

Comment: check this article - [Mocking in Ruby with Minitest](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/mocking-in-ruby-with-minitest)

Comment: Using `expect_any_instance_of` is a bad code smell in RSpec. I'm not sure you want to take that with you to MiniTest. You should probally rethink both how you structure the code and how you test it. For example stubbing `RequireSubscriptionService.call` or expecting an exception.